# When the setOnKeyListener() is implemented the back hardware button doesn't work

Tags: android, keylistener, back

The back hardware button doesn't work if an **OnKeyListener** is implemented on **myView**:

```
myView.setOnKeyListener(new EditText.OnKeyListener() {
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

             if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)
                    return false;

              /*.....more code here.....*/

        }
}
```

What I want is to get the normal behaviour of the back button, I think this should be happening since it's returning false everytime the **keyCode** it's equal to **KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK**.

**NOTE:** I'm using this code on a service

Answer (score 1):

[Check this for details](http://android-developers.blogspot.com.br/2009/12/back-and-other-hard-keys-three-stories.html)
Also, you might want to use onKeyDown instead of [onKey](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnKeyListener.html)

Depending on your version:

API 5 or less.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    // your code.
}
```

API 6 forward

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
   if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
       super.onKeyDown(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK,KeyEvent event);
       // your code
       return true;
   }
   return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Comment: You can only override this methods if the class is extending an **Activity**, and it's not, it's extending a **Service**. I am implementing a `OnKeyListener` on a view, when I do that, the device is no longer able to get the normal **back button** behaviour, not even if the method is returning false.

Comment: I am sorry, from `myView` I was considering you were using it inside a View/Activity. Can you explain in details how the service handles the view? If for instance you start an intent in the service, send a parameter to the view, and use the `onCreate` function to configure the view.... if its not like this, then explain the flow a bit more

Answer (score -1):

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK){this.finish()}

    /*.....more code here.....*/
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain your answer.

Comment: It's not it, first of all, it's not an activity, so you can't use the `finish();` method, and then stopping the service it's not the normal behaviour of the back button.

Comment: Put this code in your activity to handle the event the Back button. Or do you need exactly?

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: Even if you used this in an `Activity` it still is not correct answer. Back button does way more things than just finishing activities.